# Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: # jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$('.questionAlternative').change(function() {
    var nestedQuestion = $(this).attr('nestedQuestion');
    if(nestedQuestion != null || nestedQuestion != "") {
        $("#"+nestedQuestion).show();
    } else {
        $(this).parent().next('.nestedQuestionContainer').hide();
    }
}
```

The .questionAlternative is two radiobuttons, yes or no.

When I change to No, I get the following error:

> Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #
>   throw new Error( "Syntax error, unrecognized expression: " + msg );

I can't understand why. If nestedQuestion is empty, It should not go into the If-statement. But It seems like It doing It anyway?

Comment: `"" != null` is `true`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your condition is wrong. It says "if `nestedQuestion` is not `null` **OR** `nestedQuestion` is not `""`..." But `""` is not `null`, so that condition is true for `""`.

Change it to **and** (`&&`):

```
if(nestedQuestion != null && nestedQuestion != "") {
```

or just use the fact that both `null` and `""` are *falsy*:

```
if(nestedQuestion) {
```

..and actually, `attr` will never give you `null` anyway. It will only give you a string (possibly `""`) or `undefined`. (But `undefined == null` is true, so...)

Comment: Ah, did not know that "" was not null. Thank you.

Comment: @Bryan: :-) It's one of those things, they're both falsy, but they're not `==` to each other.